# Using \cref on a \minipage label?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, subfloats, cleveref

A couple of times I've had trouble using labels on `minipage`. I use `minipage` to create subfigures a) and b), each with their own `\subcaption` and `\label`, the whole figure also got a `\caption` with a `\label`. Then I want to use `\cref` to refer to the individual subfigures/subcaption. However when I use `\cref` with the minipage labels, it refers to the section the figure is placed.

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \def\svgwidth{0.9\columnwidth}
    \input{filepath}
    \subcaption{\textsl{Subfigure 1 text}}
    \label{fig:sub:subfigure1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \def\svgwidth{0.9\columnwidth}
    \input{filepath}
    \subcaption{\textsl{Subfigure 2 text.}}
    \label{fig:sub:subfigure2}
\end{minipage}
\caption{\textsl{Figure text.}}
\label{fig:whole_figure}
\end{figure}
```

Then I use `\cref{fig:sub:subfigure1}`, which gives me 'Section 2.3´, instead of 'Figure 4.a´ .

Also it should be noted that I use the `memoir` class, also I use the `.pdf_tex` format as figures.

I tried to read a bit in the `\cref` manual, but couldn't understand how to solve my problem, I also did some googling with no results. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a LaTeX cross-reference to some numbered "object" to work properly, the `\label` command that's associated with the object generally also has to increment the counter variable that's associated with the object via the `\refstepcounter` mechanism. Since `minipage` environments are not numbered automatically in this manner, you're finding that the `\cref` command ends up generating a cross-reference to the object that was most recently incremented via `\refstepcounter` -- in this case, a `section` or `subsection` object -- at the time the minipage's `\label` command was issued.

Fortunately, there's a solution which works very well with the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and which works both with the `memoir` class and the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, and `book`): Load the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package and use its `subfigure` environment instead of `minipage`. A `subfigure` environment, for all practical purposes, *is* the same as a `minipage` environment. The only important difference is that a `subfigure` environment is automatically associated with a counter variable that's incremented via `\refstepcounter`. Hence, cross-references to `subfigure` environments will work exactly as expected..

Incidentally, if you want all captions to be typeset automatically in *slanted-roman* text, you can tell LaTeX to do so by providing the instruction `\captionsetup{textfont = sl}`. (The `\captionsetup` macro is provided by the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, which is loaded automatically by the `subcaption` package). Doing so globally, rather than providing `\textsl` instructions separately in each and every caption, is not only convenient but will also simplify your life considerably in the future in case you decide to use a different font shape.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
   \captionsetup{textfont = sl} % use slanted font shape automatically for all captions
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{3} % just for this example
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \def\svgwidth{0.9\columnwidth}
    %\input{filepath}
    \caption{Subfigure 1 text}
    \label{fig:sub:subfigure1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \def\svgwidth{0.9\columnwidth}
    %\input{filepath}
    \caption{Subfigure 2 text.}
    \label{fig:sub:subfigure2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure text.}
\label{fig:whole_figure}
\end{figure}
\cref{fig:sub:subfigure1}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To get cross-references to subfigures formatted as "4.a" instead of "4a", you could add the following instructions in the preamble (after loading `subfigure` and before loading `cleveref`):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure.}
\makeatletter
```

The macro `\p@subfigure` serves to insert a formatted "prefix" in cross-references to items that involve `subfigure` counters. Here, the "prefix" consists of the figure number followed by a "." (dot).

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the `\label` *inside* the `\subcaption`, then it works. You can set the font of all captions and subcaptions to slanted by adding

```
\captiontitlefont{\slshape}
\subcaptionfont{\slshape}
```

As an alternative to the `minipage`s, you can use `\subbottom`, see below code.
I replaced the `\input`s with `\rule{3cm}{1cm}` which creates a black rectangle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\captiontitlefont{\slshape}
\subcaptionfont{\slshape}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\cref{fig:sub:subfigure1}

\cref{fig:sub:subfigure2}

\cref{fig:whole_figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{1cm}
    \subcaption{\textsl{Subfigure 1 text}\label{fig:sub:subfigure1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \rule{3cm}{1cm}
    \subcaption{\textsl{Subfigure 2 text.}\label{fig:sub:subfigure2}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{\textsl{Figure text.}}
\label{fig:whole_figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \subbottom[Subfigure 1 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sub1}}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subbottom[Subfigure 2 caption]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}\label{sube}}
\caption{Figure text.}
\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When making captions and subcaptions (globally) slanted, while using the memoir package, one should use `\subcaptionfont{\slshape}` (as stated by Torbjørn T.) *and* `\captiontitlefont{\slshape}` in the preamble. This will make both the caption and subcaption slanted as opposed to Torbjørn's example where `\textsl{}` is manually set in each caption.

(This should probably be a comment but my reputation is too low. Wonder why I'm allowed to answer but not comment while being a n00b?)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really notice that the main caption was set slanted as well. Silly of me. Edit: Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX!